# problem on display resolution while using VirtualBox to run Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: virtualbox

I am a new guys on Linux and I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 from VirtualBox which run on my desktop Windows 7.
After successfully installed I have found the display resolution only have 640x480 and there's no other options to select. The display only shows me that I'm using "Build in display".
Is there any way to change the display resolution to 1024x768?

Comment: You need to install the [Guest Additions](http://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-a-virtualbox-vm) in the virtual guest OS.